# how to scale image with interpolation in php gd?

Tags: php

I tried this:

```
$testJpgUrl = "./800.jpg";
$testJpgGDImage = ImageCreateFromJpeg($testJpgUrl);
echo ("Scaling\n");
$testJpgGDImage = imagescale ($testJpgGDImage , 166 , 125, IMG_BICUBIC_FIXED);
echo ("End scaling\n");
imagejpeg($testJpgGDImage,"./800Thumb.jpg",100);
```

But console output by `php script.php` is:

```
Scaling
Segmentation Fault
```

Console output by `sudo php script.php` is:

```
Scaling
```

There is no any output of `End Scaling`

When I tried `imagescale ($testJpgGDImage , 166 , 125);` everything works great but in this case image is scaled without interpolation (the same effect like in `Gimp -> scale -> interpolation: none`).
I want to scale image with interpolation (e.g like in `Gimp -> scale -> interpolation: cubic`)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `imagescale()` seems to be quite undocumented. I always use `imagecopyresampled()` and it works fine.

For quality comparison see: https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/scaling_images_in_php_done

Comment: Your method is great :) But I don't know why the function called `imagescale` have got troubles with image scaling, lol. And why this function is available in php out of a box? O.o

Comment: That is an excellent question. I guess it's the nature of open source software that this does happen from time to time. Then again it is free, so why complain? There are clearly problems: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65171

Comment: I am not complaining - i am just a little suprised ;)